# How to obtain URLs for Trello lists

Tags: trello, trello-lists

Anyone know how to link to a specific list in Trello?

By lists I refer to the columns within boards in which cards can be placed.

So I'm trying to get a link for 'Today's News List'. I've clicked around on the url and Windows app versions.  [image]

Super bonus points if you know a Slack Trello app command to archive cards, and a command to ping what cards are in a list.

Answer (score 6):

It's possible but not terribly pretty...

You need to create a link to a search that performs a board: filter and a list: filter. This will then show all the cards in that board/list.

For example, to create a URL that shows you the list "The First List" on board "My Board", the Trello markdown would be:

```
[The First List](https://trello.com/search?q=board%3A%22My%20Board%22%20list%3A%22The%20First%20List%22)
```

Note that Trello's search only works on boards you are a member of so you can't use this approach to filter a list from a public board.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to get a link to a list. One can get a link to a specific card but not a list. More info: [Trello help: sharing links to cards and boards](http://help.trello.com/article/824-sharing-links-to-cards-and-boards)